# Allen Hatcher Algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I'm trying to go through Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

But the "introduction" lost me completely. By someone's recommendation I skipped chapter 0 and drove right into chap 1, but I found that his style does not resonate with me. I don't think its very rigorously organized or pedantic.

I am acquainted with de-Rham Cohomology, but I don't know what a cohomology in general is.

I tried looking at Tammo tom Dieck's book: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf

But I read that his book is a great ***supplement*** to Hatcher, which suggests it is not good as a primary source.

I looked at Rotman's book: http://www.ugr.es/~acegarra/Rotman.pdf

I think it looks great, and from what I've seen as I skimmed through, it is in a style that I would appreciate. But my concern is that it might be outdated or it does not cover a lot of the subject.

Should I just persevere with Hatcher? Or are there other free books on algebraic topology. I'm looking for a rigorous and broad coverage of the subject.

Comment: If you're acquainted with de Rham cohomology and know some manifold theory, perhaps a good place to start is Bredon's "Topology and Geometry;" you could probably skip the first two chapters and start with the chapter on fundamental groups. There's a pdf copy available for free, hosted on Stanford's mathematics department website.

Comment: I recently asked this exact same question, you can find some suggestions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463861/looking-for-introductory-text-on-algebraic-topology-not-satisfied-with-hatcher

Also these video lectures are pretty good: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpRLWqLFLVTCL15U6N3o35g4uhMSBVA2b

Comment: I had the same problem with Hatcher. I found the first parts "hand-wavy", probably because he assumes that the reader has more knowledge of the basics than I had. Then I read Rotman's book cover to cover, along with Munkres' "Elements of Algebraic Topology". They cover the same material in slightly different ways, which helped me see "the big picture". THEN I went back to Hatcher, and discovered what a gem it really is.

Comment: I've looked at Brendon's book, at it seems like a great fit for me. I will perhaps read Tom Dieck's book as a supplement to it. Just a quick concern: I've studied algebra from Thomas W. Judson's "Abstract Algebra," but I'm afraid it is too elementary. It seems to have been written for high school students. Should I re-study algebra with a more advanced and rigorous text or is Judson sufficient as a background in algebra? http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20130816.pdf